# Can heard audio but state couldn't be confirmed and call end after 20->30s pjsip

Tags: sip, pjsip

i'm using react-native-pjsip

It works normally on Android 
But i can hear audio but state couldn't be confirmed and call end automatically after 20-30s.

Comment: more info please

Comment: I got incoming call with status PJSIP_INV_STATE_NULL -> PJSIP_INV_STATE_INCOMING -> PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING  . But no PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED .